# How to run after all javascript ES6 Promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm in the process of replacing some old code that used jQuery Deferred objects and I am rewriting using Bluebird/ES6 Promises.

If I have multiple asynchronous calls, how can I trigger a function after all the promises are resolved.

Using jQuery Deferreds it would be something like this:

```
var requests = [...]; //some arbitrary data that is iterated to generate multiple ajax requests
var promises = [];
resuests.forEach(function(endpoint) {
    promises.push($.ajax({url: endpoint}));
});

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    alert('all promises complete!');
});
```

How do I rewrite this using ES6 Promise syntax?

Comment: With jQuery promise syntax that could be `$.when.apply($, requests.map($.get)).then(...` - much cleaner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Note that it *takes an iterable* such as an Array as its argument, unlike `$.when`, so doesn't need the `.apply`.

You'll also want to convert the jQuery Deferred to a native ES6 promise using [`Promise.resolve(thejQueryDeferred)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve). **EDIT: This gets done implicitly by the call to `Promise.all`, so is really optional.**

Whole code:

```
var requests = [...]; //some arbitrary data that is iterated to generate multiple ajax requests
var promises = [];
requests.forEach(function(endpoint) {
    var nativePromise = Promise.resolve($.ajax({url: endpoint})); // if you want to make it clear that you're converting from jQuery Deferred to ES6 promise!
    promises.push(nativePromise);
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    alert('all promises complete!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, updated. Note that simply `Promise.resolve(thejQueryDeferred)` is enough to convert a jQuery Deferred to an ES6 Promise (`Promise.resolve` checks for the `then` property and acts accordingly).

Comment: @dfsq actually - it is. Native promises were built around the Promises/A+, which in turn is built in such a way consuming jQuery promises is possible. This is intended.

Comment: As for the `.resolve` comment - you actually don't need to do this, the `Promise.resolve` is automatically done for you when a native promises consumes a foreign `then`able. You can see this in the spec (or even MDN, which you linked to).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Good point. I should've stood my ground :-) I'm going to stick with the explicit conversion in my answer as I prefer the clarity, but thank you for a valid point.

Comment: For the record - all promise methods do this, `.then` does this, and so on. Assimilation is a core concept in the spec. Otherwise - interoping between different promise libraries would have been really hard :)

Comment: +1 for being first with a correct answer. I have to accept the @BenjaminGruenbaum answer though as I believe it provides the most in-depth answer and includes Bluebird syntax. I really appreciate your answer too though.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is tagged [bluebird](/questions/tagged/bluebird) in addition to the two good solutions you have already gotten here is a more "bluebird" way:

```
var requests = [...];

Promise.map(requests, $.get).then(function(results){
    alert('all promises complete!');
});
```

This is probably as simple as it gets.

As the others have pointed out, the native es6 way would be to use `Promise.all`, no `Promise.resolve` or explicit creation is needed. The cleanest way with native promises would probably be:

```
var requests = [...];
Promise.all(requests.map($.get)).then(function(results){

});
```

Comment: Great answer really and I appreciate the Bluebird syntax. I'm currently using Bluebird, but may stick to the native syntax as I may consider removing Bluebird when ES6 is officially supported in major browsers.