# Imbricated promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, httprequest

**What I want to do :** get a list of projects (from API), request the status for each project. And call a callback who should represent the global status of my projects.

**How I am trying to do it :** the first ***promise*** get all projects and in the first ***then*** I am trying to call for each project a getProjectStatus who should get the status. I want that my second ***then*** wait that I finished the iteration (I tried many different things, but my second then is always called before). I don't know if this is a good using of promises...

```
  var that = this;
  var options = { url : this.host + "projects", json : true }

  var finalStatus = "SUCCESS";

  // first promises
  return request(this.options)
  .then(function(projects) { 
    projects.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        // second promises
        that.getProjectStatus(element.id, function(status){})
        .then(function(status) {
            if(status != "SUCCESS)
            {
                finalStatus = "FAILURE";
            }
        });
    })
  })
  .then(function(){
      callback(finalStatus)});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run after all javascript ES6 Promises are resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634654/how-to-run-after-all-javascript-es6-promises-are-resolved)

Comment: I think there are many versions of this question, but that was the first one I could find. In any case, this is covered as an example in the docs for just about every Promise implementation.

Comment: Hey Mathletics, I was aware of Promise.all, but I was not able to use it correctly, I didn't found the way to use it in my imbrication (As I said I tried to implemented it in the second then). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going. You just use `Promise.all` on the array of second promises.  I may not have understood the exact syntax of `getProjectStatus` but you can adjust I hope if needs be

```
  return request(this.options)
  .then(function(projects) {
    return Promise.all( projects.map(element => that.getProjectStatus(element.id) )

  .then(function(){
      callback(finalStatus)});
```

Comment: Oh awesome I tried with Promise.all in the second then (adding promise in  array and return it) without luck.