# Promise.all is not waiting for the functions to finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

Im playing around with some async calls (`AXIOS` calls) involving promises. The problem with the code is the `this.reloadData()` gets called before `this.updateUsers()` and `this.updateEmails()` executed and finished. What is the right way to wait for the two functions finish, and then call `this.reloadData()` ?

`rest.putEmail` and `rest.putUser` are both **axios** REST API calls.

```
mainFunc() {
         Promise.all([this.updateUsers(), this.updateEmails()]).then(() => {
              this.reloadData();
         })
```

}

```
updateEmails() {
    const {emails} = this.state;
    if (emails.length > 0) {
         emails.map(user => {
               rest.putEmail(email.id, email.content)
                   .catch(err => {this.error(err)});
          });
    }
}

updateUsers() {
        const {users} = this.state;
        if (users.length > 0) {
             users.map(user => {
                   rest.putUser(user.id, user.name)
                       .catch(err => {this.error(err)});
              });
          }
    }
```

Comment: In order for this to work, your functions need to return promises

Comment: @dave im calling rest calls for each item in a collection. How could i wrap all of this into a promise and then return it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run after all javascript ES6 Promises are resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634654/how-to-run-after-all-javascript-es6-promises-are-resolved)

Comment: @ssss You are already doing it in your first function: `Promise.all()` is the answer.

Comment: Closely related: [Promise.all is returning an array of undefined and resolves before being done](/q/34813147/4642212), [How to use Promise.all() after Promises created in for loop](/q/42180299/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, your `updateEmails()` and `updateUsers()` functions do not return promises and `Promise.all` accepts an array of *promises* as an argument. In this case, you're passing undefined as an argument to `Promise.all` so it doesn't wait for `updateEmails()` or `updateUsers()` to execute.

To solve this issue, you need to put all of your promise calls into an array, supply the array to `Promise.all`, and return that in both the `updateEmails()` and `updateUsers()` functions.

```
mainFunc() {
  Promise.all([this.updateUsers(), this.updateEmails()]).then(() => {
    this.reloadData();
  })
}

updateEmails() {
  const {emails} = this.state;
  if (emails.length > 0) {
    const promises = emails.map(user => {
        rest.putEmail(email.id, email.content)
            .catch(err => {this.error(err)});
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
}

updateUsers() {
  const {users} = this.state;
  const promises = [];
  if (users.length > 0) {
    const promises = users.map(user => {
      rest.putUser(user.id, user.name)
        .catch(err => {this.error(err)});
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
}
```

Whenever you call `.map` on both the emails and users arrays, an array of promises is returned which is stored in the `const promises` in both functions. Now you can simply pass these promises to `Promise.all` and return the promise returned from `Promise.all`. Now your `Promise.all` call inside of your `mainFunc()` is receiving promises it needs to wait for and won't call `this.reloadData()` until both functions have finished executing.